# Minimum of 4th Element in NxNx4 list (Python)

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

Hi I've been reading up on finding the minimum of a multidimensional list, but if I have an N x N x 4 list, how do I get the minimum between every single 4th element? All other examples have been for a small example list using real indices. I suppose I'll be needing to define indices in terms of N....

`[[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],...N],[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],...N].....N]`

And then there's retrieving their indices.

I don't know what to try.

If anyone's interested in the actual piece of code:

```
relative = [[[[100] for k in range(5)] for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)]
```

What the following does is fill in the 4th element with times satisfying the mathematical equations. The 0th, 1st, 2nd and 3rd elements of `relative` have positions and velocities. The 4th spot is for the time taken for the i and jth particles to collide (redundant values such as i-i or j-i are filled with the value 100 (because it's big enough for the min function not to retrieve it). I need the shortest collision time (hence the 4th element comparisons)

```
def time(relative):
i = 0
t = 0
while i<N: 
    j = i+1
    while j<N and i<N:
        rv = relative[i][j][0]*relative[i][j][2]+relative[i][j][1]*relative[i][j][3]     #Dot product of r and v
        if rv<0:
            rsquared = (relative[i][j][0])**2+(relative[i][j][1])**2
            vsquared = (relative[i][j][2])**2+(relative[i][j][3])**2
            det = (rv)**2-vsquared*(rsquared-diameter**2)
            if det<0:
                t = 100                        #For negative times, assign an arbitrarily large number to make sure min() wont pick it up.
            elif det == 0:
                t = -rv/vsquared
            elif det>0:
                t1 = (-rv+sqrt((rv)**2-vsquared*(rsquared-diameter**2)))/(vsquared)
                t2 = (-rv-sqrt((rv)**2-vsquared*(rsquared-diameter**2)))/(vsquared)
                if t1-t2>0:
                    t = t2
                elif t1-t2<0:
                    t = t1
        elif rv>=0:
            t = 100
        relative[i][j][4]=t                 #Put the times inside the relative list for element ij.
        j = j+1
    i = i+1
return relative
```

I've tried:
`t_fin = min(relative[i in range(0,N-1)][j in range(0,N-1)][4])`
Which compiles but always returns 100 even thought I've checked it isnt the smallest element.

Comment: Can you give examples for you case? simple examples.

Comment: You should consider using `numpy`

Comment: I've edited the post to have more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `min` of 4th element of NxNx4 list,

```
min([x[3] for lev1 in relative for x in lev1])
```